# Is it possible to use Select(l=> new{}) with SelectMany in EntityFramework

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I am trying something that i not really sure but i want to ask here if it s possible.

Is it able to be done ?

```
public IQueryable<Info> GetInfo(int count, byte languageId)
        {
            return db.Info.SelectMany(i => i.LanguageInfo)
                              .Where(l => l.Language.id == languageId)
                              .Select(l => new Info {   AddDate = l.Info.AddDate,
                                                        Description = l.Description,
                                                        EntityKey = l.Info.EntityKey,
                                                        id = l.Info.id,
                                                        Title = l.Title,
                                                        ViewCount = l.Info.ViewCount }
                                                        )
                              .OrderByDescending(i => i.id)
                              .Take(count);
        }
```

When this method is executed i got an error

> The entity or complex type
>   'GuideModel.Info' cannot be
>   constructed in a LINQ to Entities
>   query.

Does it mean "not possible" ?

Thank you

Comment: What does the definition of class "Info" look like?

Comment: Info Class | Id,Title,Description,AddDate,Viewcount

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error essentially indicates that the Entity Framework doesn't know how to create an Info object, since it is not bound to a table object. (Put another way, the `Select` call on the `IQueryable` cannot be translated into equivalent SQL.) You could perform the `Select` projection on the client via:

```
public IQueryable<Info> GetInfo(int count, byte languageId)
{
    return db.Info.SelectMany(i => i.LanguageInfo)
                      .Where(l => l.Language.id == languageId)
                      .Take(count)
                      .AsEnumerable()
                      .Select(l => new Info {   AddDate = l.Info.AddDate,
                                                Description = l.Description,
                                                EntityKey = l.Info.EntityKey,
                                                id = l.Info.id,
                                                Title = l.Title,
                                                ViewCount = l.Info.ViewCount }
                                                )
                      .OrderByDescending(i => i.id);
}
```

Comment: Thank you, after some experiments i almost came up the same code like yours and now i see yours

Comment: The first two sentences of this answer have the facts exactly backwards. The Entity Framework *can* create POCOs in a queryable expression. Translating the query into SQL is also not a problem; that's how it can project onto POCOs. It can also create EntityObject subtypes when materializing them from the DB. What it cannot do is create EntityObject subtypes without materializing them from the DB. Doing so would make them kind of "half in" and "half out of" the ObjectContext, which would be weird.

Comment: Craig: sorry, I was thinking LINQ-to-SQL at the time. Thank you for the clarification. The solution still stands, though.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible to use `Select(l => new ...)`, but not with an Entity type. You need to use an anonymous type or a POCO type with a parameterless constructor. Entity types are "special" because of the way they interact with the ObjectContext. You can select them, but not new them up in a query.

Answer (score 0):

The code below worked for me. Here "SearchTerm" is a complex type. Thanks Jason :)

```
var lstSynonym = TechContext.TermSynonyms
                .Where(p => p.Name.StartsWith(startLetter))
                .AsEnumerable()
                .Select(u => new SearchTerm
                                 {
                                     ContentId = u.ContentId,
                                     Title = u.Name,
                                     Url = u.Url
                                 });
```